# i Can't solve Oracle db 21c express edition installation problem

Tags: database, oracle, express

During installation of Oracle db 21c Express Edition

Check the status of the environment variable installation part
Make sure ORACLE_HOME and TNS_ADMIN are not set.
I was wondering what this means, so I tried it without oracle_home, but there is a problem even if I install oracle_home

If I open a cmd window and type sqlplus oracle_home it is set up fine.
Version can be checked

However, prerequisite checks cannot install environment variables.
Not working after reboot[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dIux2.png)

Comment: Please post the code  or error as text in your question, not an image.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the environment variable as it is, it is case sensitive use `ORACLE_HOME` instead of oracle_home, and same for `TNS_ADMIN`

Comment: I did it with ORACLE_HOME

Comment: I've tried several different methods.
The ORACLE_HOME variable setting is perfect.
But TNS_ADMIIN is the problem.
Other sites tell me to set the variable by copying the network file address of the Oracle client file.
I tried this too, same result

Comment: the TNS_ADMIN is an environmental variable which is recognized by the Oracle kernel..The default value of TNS_ADMIN will be the path where you tnsnames.ora & listener.ora exists by default..So to change the path of tnsnames.ora or listener.ora you need to change the value of the TNS_ADMIN variable..So go to command prompt and type :

c:\> set TNS_ADMIN="give the path where you want to point the tnsnames.ora"